# How to concanicate string to an array item which is also of type string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings

```
var originalText = [
"Sample Text",
"More Text"
];

var extraString = "extra text to be appended";
```

I want to concatenate extraString to each of the entry in originalText, so final output is

```
originalText = [
"Sample Text extra text to be appended",
"More Text extra text to be appended"
]
```

Comment: Iterate array and modify each element instance. Not difficult. Please show what you have tried. This isn't a coding service or tutorial service. You are expected to have researched the problem yourself and show code that isn't working as expected

Comment: use for loop and concatenate with array element

Comment: Downvoted: you don't know how to 1) loop and 2) get elements by index? These are very basic things, please refer documentation before asking such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and append every element with the wanted string.

```js
var originalText = [
    "Sample Text",
    "More Text"
];

var extraString = "extra text to be appended";

originalText.forEach(function(_, i, aa) {
    aa[i] += ' ' + extraString;
});

console.log(originalText);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is using `map` because you don't mutate the originalText:

```js
var originalText = [
  "Sample Text",
  "More Text"
];

var extraString = "extra text to be appended";

//Using map
var editedText = originalText.map(x => x + extraString);

//Output edited text
console.log(editedText);
// => [
//  "Sample Textextra text to be appended",
//  "More Textextra text to be appended"
//]

//Output original text
console.log(originalText);
// => [
//  "Sample Text",
//  "More Text"
//]
```

And maybe a beauty solution with map:

```
const originalText = [
  "Sample Text",
  "More Text"
];

const appendExtraString = t => t + "extra text to be appended";
const editedText = originalText.map(appendExtraString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array and append the text to every item. Look at this example:

```
    var originalText = ['Array 1', 'Array 2'];
    var text = "APPENDED";
    for(i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++) {
        originalText[i] = originalText[i] + text;
    }
```

You just need to adapt this example to your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalText = [
"Sample Text",
"More Text"
];

var extraString = " extra text to be appended";

for(var i = 0; i<originalText.length; i++ ){
   originalText[i] = originalText[i] +extraString ;
}
```